# Change API path name while listing API's

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

We are documenting all the API's from the application for this we are using [swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui)

Here is sample code for it

```
exports.people = {
  'spec':
  {
    path : "/people",
    method: "POST",
    summary : "Create new person",
    notes : "Create new person",
    nickname : "people",    
    parameters : [param.query("email", "email", "string", true), 
                  param.query("firstName", "firstName", "string", true),
                  param.query("lastName", "lastName", "string", true)]   
  },
  'action': function(req, res)
  {

        -----code----
  }
}
```

it generating Request URL as

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/api/people
```

So it is generating path for people as `/people` but we have to change it to "/create_people' so how can we implement this functionality.

we tried this by changing "path" of the `spec` here is the code

```
exports.people = {
  'spec':
  {
    path : "/create_people",
    .....// rest of code
```

it is working but it creating different redirect url as follow

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/api/create_people
```

which is wrong we have to change only API name not request URL.

here is the pictorial representation. [image]

we are using **swagger-ui** and **node.js**

Comment: What's you're asking doesn't make a lot of sense. The "/people" is part of the documentation - it is the actual path being used. You're looking to change the display but run the operation against the actual path. Can't really see why you'd want to do that, it will only confuse your users.

Comment: my client want it and is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by saying this is generally not a good idea. The purpose of the documentation is to explain the users the available operations and here you want to hide direct information. After all, you have the description "Create new person" on the right side of that column.

Setting that aside, accomplishing that with Swagger 1.2 is not an easy task. You'd have to hack both the Swagger documentation and the UI to get the output that you want. Other third party tools that you may want to consume the hacked spec may not work properly as well.

In Swagger 2.0 you can use the `x-` extension properties, and have something like `"x-alternative-display": "/create_person"` and then you can change the UI so that it uses that attribute instead of the path for display.